# I am unable to ping my Azure Sql database, its working fine from months

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL database working perfectly from last 3 months, from last 3 days its not working, i am unable to ping Azure SQL Server, and on saving information i get error 'A Network related instance cannot be created'. I didn't even change the passwords or connection strings. System firewall is off. 
I have already tried different ways such as password change, connection string regenerate but the problem still persists. If i am login on portal it says all perfect, IP added, no IP is blacklist.

Comment: What's about your subscription? is it still valid?

Comment: Yes it is valid, i have Pay as You Go Subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to connect using SQLCMD to verify it is or it is not a firewall issue. Error message will be more detailed.

```
SQLCMD –U<user>@<server> -P<password> -S<server>.database.windows.net
```

The ping command is supposed to give you a timeout because SQL Azure servers never respond to ping requests, but above the timeout replies it tells you the actual IP of your SQL Azure server. Use that IP to telnet your SQL Azure server. If ping command does not return an IP then there is a DNS resolution issue on your network.

```
C:\> ping <myserver>.database.windows.net

C:\> telnet 65.55.74.144 1433
```

If the telnet command is not successful then use the tracert utility to know intermediate steps taken while trying to reach the server.

Hope this helps.